# Computed Hierarchyid Column

Tags: sql-server-2008, hierarchy

I have a table that uses a ParentID column; the standard way of representing a hierarchy.

I have read about all the goodies of hierarchyid and need it to query all records that have a specific ancestor.  The problem is that converting the table to use hierarchyid would require many changes that I currently do not have time for.

Is it possible to create:

**a computed column that is of type hierarchyid**

OR

**an indexed view of that table with a hierarchyid**

I thought of making a function that computes the hierarchyid recursively but that would not be good in terms of performance.

Comment: Have look at using a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx). You can use it to build the hierarchy id or to do the actual query you need.

Comment: Thanks, I used a recursive CTE to build a view that expands the ancestors of each child. My table has a few thousand records and it runs smoothly.  If you promote your comment to an answer I could mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at using a [reqursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I used the following recursive CTE in a view:
WITH ancestorCte(AncestorID, ID) AS (SELECT ParentID, ID FROM dbo.MyTable AS t                                                                   UNION ALL
SELECT p.AncestorID, c.ID
FROM dbo.MyTable AS c INNER JOIN
ancestorCte AS p ON c.ParentID = P.ID)

SELECT AncestorID, ID FROM ancestorCte